# passing arguments between files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have two python QT apps - MainApp and Editor. I want both to be able to run independently so that you can run Editor by itself or you could open editor from mainApp and pass its arguments to the editor.

mocap code:

first.py

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from second import Editor

class MainApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__ (self, parent=None):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__(parent) 

        self.myArg = "hello"
        Editor(self, self.myArg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QMainWindow()
    MainApp = MainApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

second.py

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow

class Editor(QMainWindow):
    def __init__ (self, myArg, parent=None):
        self.myArg = myArg
        super(Editor, self).__init__(parent) 

        print(self.myArg)
```

When I am trying to pass some data from mainApp (first.py) to second.py I am getting en error:

```
TypeError: QMainWindow(parent: QWidget = None, flags: Union[Qt.WindowFlags, Qt.WindowType] = Qt.WindowFlags()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
```

Comment: `MainApp = MainApp()` can be very dangerous.

Comment: you are 100% right :) I am mocking up code to illustrate the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editor `__init__()` method takes a string (`myArg`) and an optional parent, and you give it an `MainApp` (`self`) and a string. The `MainApp` can't be converted in `string` so you have a `TypeError`.

I think you misunderstood the `self` parameter of the method `__init__()`. You don't have to provide it yourself, because Python gives the object that is currently being initialized to the method. Just changing this line should work:

```
Editor(self.myArg)
```